# Is there a common term for source and destination?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**Background:**
I'm trying to come up with a name for a database column.
This would store the source or destination of funds in a multi-part financial transaction.

Comment: Origin, perhaps?

Comment: Origin means source, but not destination, right?

Comment: In communications you might collectively call them *endpoints*.  I don't think that fits in your financial example. Do you really not differentiate between source and destination?  You might call them *Parties*

Comment: Whoops, misread.

Comment: @Jim: I do differentiate, via positive vs. negative amounts (It's [double-entry bookkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system)).  Parties is pretty close, but these are actually quite often categories (like "income" or "mortgage") or accounts (like "checking" or "credit card").

Comment: "Income, mortgage, checking, credit..." Why not simply "transaction type"? Or "settlement"?

Comment: I retract a lurid suggestion....

Comment: In DE Bookkeeping aren't they all called **accounts**?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing names for things in programs.

Comment: @Jim, thank you! spent like an hour looking for the right term and  *endpoint* was perfect for my context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the *type* of source or destination. For example, if the source and destination are accounts, then a few folks already suggested "account". If the source and destination are companies, individuals, etc., then you use or prefix "partner", "foreign", "customer" or similar words with some indication of the *type* of source/destination. If it's a computer system, "partner" might still work, e.g.:

- "Partner", "PartnerEntity", "PartnerAccount", ...
- "Foreign", "ForeignEntity", "ForeignAccount", ...
- "TransactionEntity", "TransactionAccount", ...
- "TransferEntity", "TransferAccount", ...

In a computer system, especially in databases, people sometimes prefer longer names too, such as "SourceOrDestinationAccount" and usually another column elsewhere gives an indication whether its a source or destination. I prefer longer names to ensure clarity, so I could name it this way.

Hopefully, one of these will help...

Comment: @tchrist: I agree that this is a bit off-topic here, & I registered in English just because I couldn't resist not responding to this one. However, if it were in programmers stack exchange, it would have been more suitable, and I wouldn't have to register here :-) And I can't even comment on the main thread due to not having enough reputation here!

Answer (score 2):

station- a regular stopping place on a public transportation route.

so a station can be an origin or a destination.

also:

terminal- A departure and arrival building

Answer (score 0):

**Balance**

..But with a qualifier:

- [Multi_Balance]
- [Running_Bal]
- [Ongoing_Bal]
- [Provisional_Bal]
- [Composite_Bal]
- [Conglomerate_Bal]
- [Interim_Bal]
- [Transient_Bal]
- [Provisional_Bal]
- [Shift_Account]
- [Reposition]
- [Flux]
- [Interchange]
- [Medley]
- [Olio]
  …

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "account" would be a typical description. The word is both generic, as in "accounting," and specific, as in "house account," or "escrow account." For instance, an account at a bank or brokerage is an entity unto itself, with a name, and defining characteristics, such tax status, joint or individual ownership, etc. The various accounts within the banking and brokerage systems become waypoints as money clears from payer account, through the clearing houses, to payee account.