# Common term for Source & Destination

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, common-word

What is the hypernym of Destination & Source?  For example,

> The information will be verified to fit all relevant criteria at all [source and destination points].

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Unfortunately, Naming, including naming programming variables/classes is [explicitly off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -- but if you can [make your question on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word) then it might be re-opened.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: However, I'd suggest `Terminals`.

Comment: Should I ask this question in Stack overflow ?

Comment: I saw a similar question, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177389/is-there-a-common-term-for-source-and-destination.
Anyway didn't know where to ask, but thanks.

Comment: Check their Help pages to see what's on-topic. I doubt that any site will consider naming questions, because you can name your class *Susan* and it will work successfully. If you remove all mention of naming and simply ask what is a hypernym of *source* and *destination,* it will probably be on-topic here (even the duplicate you found is off-topic, because it's about naming). Naming is a no-no.

Comment: Question changed.

Comment: OK... But it will be closed for lack of research. Check synonyms of both words; a synonym of both may be a hypernym. Show your research in your question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Funnily enough I was going to say *termini*. For some inexplicable reason it made me think of the *source and destination* of a Piccadilly Line train, which used to be Osterley (now Heathrow) and Cockfosters. And what are these?  *Termini* of course!

Comment: I think they're "words".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what is known as communication theory, the endpoints are the source and destination of a message. That said, I would not called that a "hypernym"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematical_Theory_of_Communication